# Android studio couldn't installed on Ubuntu

Tags: android, linux, ubuntu, android-studio

I have downloaded sdk from google website, after installing I clicked new project, set application name and target device then when clicking the next button the android studio shows the error below;

https://screencloud.net/v/pA7J

I'm sure there is no problem on java, jdk and internet connection side.
What would be the problem ?

Comment: Ubuntu 64 bit or 32 bit

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade 64bit

Comment: @MaheshwarLigade why did you ask ?

Comment: @kiko what I need for disable firewall ?

Comment: 32 bit has some issue thats why may its issue with firewall as @kiko said

Answer (score 1):

As @kiko mentioned, this problem occurs because of firewall.

I just type;

```
sudo ufw disable
```

on ubuntu 15.10 and works.